# Galaxy S6 stuck on logo screen

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I was installing trying to install custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy S6. I have done it previously without problem. I booted up in recovery mode(TWRP) and performed advanced wipe. I checked Dalvik/ART cache, system, cache and data. After wipe was done i pressed reboot button. After that my phone was stuck on Samsung logo screen(the one that says Samsung Galaxy S6 powered by android).

I tried to boot up in recovery and download mode but it just gets stuck on that logo screen. I just want to boot in recovery mode to install ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just realized you can go into recovery mode(volume down+home+power button) even when you are on logo screen. Hope it helps